# Execute javascript after page loaded and the page (intern) javascript finished

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, pageload

I am looking for a function/methode to execute my javascript (using greasemonkey) after the page fully loaded and page javascript finished.

Already tried the following ways but they are running the testscript after the page loaded **but before** the javascript finishs.

```
    window.onload = function () { testscript() }

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {  testscript()})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting your `window.onload` after all `script` `tags`, like so -> `<script>...</script> <script> window.onload = function () { testscript() } </script>` ? Also, all your `scripts` should be at the end of the page.

Comment: I think the whole script is already within <script> and </script> in Greasemonkey. Still tried it out and got a SyntaxError :/

Comment: What kind of SyntaxError? Also, can you post a `jsfiddle` example?

Comment: I don't quite know what's jsfiddle but I hope this will help:
http://jsfiddle.net/f46cC/1/

Comment: `Greasemonkey` is a `Firefox` addon, and `Tampermonkey` is a `Chrome` extension (the same as `Greasemonkey` but for `Chrome`).

Comment: So basically I want to refresh the page after the page itself and the javascript finished loading.

Comment: Do you understand, that refreshing the page after it has finished loading, will put your page in an endless loop ? Take a look at this demo http://jsbin.com/vabudane/2/edit ?

Comment: I have already tried out the setTimeout function but I'm looking more for another way: To execute the script right after the page finishs loading.

Comment: Remove the `setTimeout` and it will immediately redirect you to the specified page. I've put it to make the change of the border color more visible before the page is redirected.

Comment: Add a `script` `tag` to the end of your page and without using `window.onload`, execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to simply use `setTimeout` to wait a bit after loading to give the other scripts a chance to execute first, then run the script.

In this example, I have an alert code execute 3 seconds after the page finishes loading, which in most cases would be plenty of time to allow for all other scripts to execute first. You can adjust as needed for your purposes.

```
// @name     New Script
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            // your code here
            alert("3 seconds after load"); 
      }, 3000);
}, false);
```